# Is there a limit on the number of rows a sum function can calculate in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to sum a column of 50938 values in Excel 2007 but keep receiving a "#VALUE!" error. The cells in the column do contain formulas. I also tried to sum the column after copying and pasting values but received the same error.

Comment: There is a limit to the size of the numbers themselves.  You may be exceeding the maximum number size if these are large numbers.  Do you know how large the result will be or a rough average value for the cells?

Comment: The average value for these cells is about 20.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. You may want to take a look at [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa). Also, take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that none of the formulas evaluate to an error? An easy way to do this is to add an autofilter and then filter for items containing #.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any spaces in the column. Excel won't SUM() if you do.

Comment: You can also use the formula check feature to walk through the calculation until you find what is causing the error.

Comment: 255 arguments per function

Comment: One of the cells had an error. I fixed that and am having no issues now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With regard to limits on the *SUM()* function, I filled **ALL** of column **A** with the value *20* and `=sum(A:A)` calculated properly.

If there are any errors in column **A** or text values, then the *array formula*:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A:A),A:A))
```

should work.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.